# Select multiple list elements based on their names using a vector

Tags: r, list, select, subset, names

I have a list with named elements, called `namedlist`.

I want to select some of the elements based on their names, as stored in a vector.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646098/select-list-element-based-on-their-name) tells me how to do it to select *a single* element:

```
namedlist <- list(c("fff", "gggg", "hhh"), c("xxx", "yyy", "zzz"), c("pp", "ooo"), c("lll"))
names(namedlist) <- c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD")

# only select the element AA
namedlist[grep("AA", names(namedlist))]
```

However, I want to select *multiple* elements from that list.

I have the names of the elements I want to select stored in a vector, `needed`.

```
needed <- c("AA", "DD")
```

However, the following code does not work:

```
namedlist[grep(needed, names(namedlist))]
```

How can I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subscripting:

```
namedlist[needed]
## $AA
## [1] "fff"  "gggg" "hhh" 
##
## $DD
## [1] "lll"

namedlist$AA
## [1] "fff"  "gggg" "hhh" 

namedlist[["AA"]] # same
## [1] "fff"  "gggg" "hhh" 

namedlist["AA"] # same except it returns a sublist
## $AA
## [1] "fff"  "gggg" "hhh"
```